# 7pt fonts in do not render correctly in Excel 2010?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-excel-2010

Excel 2010 seems to default to some kind of global font when the font size is set to smaller than 8pt, such as 7pt. Is there a way to have Excel render 7pt fonts as Word would render them?

Screenshot Examples:

**Consolas 8pt font**
[image: Consolas 8pt font]

**Consolas 7pt font**
[image: Consolas 7pt font] (doesn't look like Consolas)

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: *Edited to include screenshots

Comment: Out of Curiousity I made a test with 7pt Consolas.  When you zoom to 120%, the font restores to look like Consolas, so this is a rendering issue. (Not saying it wasn't, but it's good to debug)

Comment: Theo-Excellent observation, I didn't notice that!